# Nativescript-slides plugin + Vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to use [nativescript-slide](https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-slides) with NativeScript Vue. The slider works as expected but I cannot find how to listen for the events.

```html
<SlideContainer loop="true" height="100%" width="100%" @changed="doSomething">
    <!-- [...] -->
</SlideContainer>
```

Is someone know how I have to write this to make `doSomething` fire ?
Or simply how I can listen for the `changed` event ?

Comment: I am trying to test it, but I am getting the error: 
`ERROR in ../node_modules/nativescript-slider/slider-common.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ui/core/proxy' in '/Users/tralves/code/ns-vue/test-slider/node_modules/nativescript-slider'`. How did you solve this?

Comment: Also, are you on NS 4.2.0?

Comment: @TiagoA. I am on NativeScript 4.2.2. I did nothing more than installing the dependency so I guess it should work... Hav you tried to clear and re-build the whole project ? With nativescript-cli, this is required.

Comment: did you figure it out? Can you share the solution?